# How to compare class objects?

Tags: java

I want to compare two objects. However, it tells me they do not match when I run it, even though they do. Please let me know what I am doing wrong, thank you. Here is my code:

```
      Player p1 = new Player("Mo", "Food", 200.0,0.0);
      Player p2 = new Player("Mo", "Food", 200.0,0.0);
      
      System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // -- false
```

Comment: Does your Player class override the "equals" method? 
By default, equals does not compare a custom class' inner state.
So if you don't override the equals method in your Player class, then equals will be true ONLY if p and p2 are literally the same

Answer (score 8):

Your `equals()` is calling the default `Object` class's method, which compares the Objects's identity<sup>*</sup>, that is, `p1==p2`, not its contents. This is the default `equals` from `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

If you want to define your logic in order to decide if two `Player`s are equal, you need to **override**:

- [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method
- `hashCode()` method to honor the equals-hash contract

---

```
class Player {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double score;
    private double rating;

    // ...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, score, rating);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Player other = (Player) obj;
        return Objects.equals(firstName, other.firstName) && Objects.equals(lastName, other.lastName)
                && score == other.score && rating == other.rating;
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Java SE 16

[Java 16 Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature helps you get rid of all this boilerplate code. Most of the ceremonial code mentioned above is automatically available to you with just the following declaration:

```
record Point(String firstName, String lastName, double score, double rating) { }
```

---

***If you want to work with Collections:***

- **Implement** `Comparable` *-- this won't let you directly compare,  but useful for collections*
- **Implement** `Comparator`

If you want to work with Collections, in order to be able to sort, for example, you could implement the `Comparable` interface. *This avoids breaking the equals and hashcode contract, which is pretty difficult to achieve manually*.

As ***Holger*** comments (*he's giving me some lessons today*) use this when there's a numeric based ordering involved.

If not, you can use the `Comparator` interface.

In this example I'm using Comparable:

```
class Player implements Comparable<Player> 
{
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Player p2)  
   {
      /* Allows returning : (0)-> this==p2 | (1)-> this>p2 | (-1)-> this<p2
        Anyway, the meaning of 1 and -1 is up to you.
        if (this.name.equals(p2.name) && ...)
           return 0;
       else if ... 
            return 1;
       return -1;     */
   }
}
```

---

<sup>* Thanks to ***Henry Twist*** for pointing this out.</sup>

Comment: As far as I am aware the default Java implementation of equals is reference equality not hashcode? If you look at the source we just have return (this == obj);

Comment: That's the default Object equals method. Subclasses override it, for example, String. Without it, `String a = "name"; String b="name"; a.equals(b)` would never be true. And that's exactly why strings should never be compared with `==`, which is an usual mistake

Comment: @HenryTwist Anyway, you have a point with the hashCode comment. I updated the answer to avoid misleading this. You were right with that-- The point is that there's a contract between hashcode and equals, which shouldn't be broken. If two objects are equals as per ==, then their hashCode must be equal. The usual overriding of equals consists in comparing hashCodes

Comment: To avoid breaking the equals and hashcode contract, you have to override the `hashCode` method. This is not even remotely related to implementing `Comparable`. In fact, you shouldn’t implement `Comparable` for things that don’t have a *natural order*. You can easily sort such objects using a dedicated `Comparator`, e.g. `Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)`. There are different ways to sort such objects and you can have different `Comparator`s. And, by the way, instead of `if(condition) return true;  [else] return false;` you can simply write `return condition;`.

Answer (score 4):

with the new **record** class type this is finally addressed.

```
    record Player(String name, String item, double val1, double val2){}

    Player p1 = new Player("Mo", "Food", 200.0, 0.0);
    Player p2 = new Player("Mo", "Food", 200.0, 0.0);

    System.out.println("equals:"+p1.equals(p2));
    System.out.println("==:"+(p1==p2));
```

will print

```
   equals:true
   ==:false
```